# $.post not being executed in safari and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, post, safari

I have this request:

```
var sendObj = {
  requested_full_post_id: id // some INT Value
}
console.log("fullpost sollte angezeigt werden");
$.post('/api/get/singlepost', sendObj, function(result){
  console.log(result);
});
```

It's a regular POST request that sends an Object to the server. Weirdly when I try to execute this in safari and chrome, the POST request doesn't get executed.
No error in the browser, no error on the server. Just as if nothing happened.

I'd appreciate any help :)

Comment: If this code is getting executed, then there must be a request in the network tab in developer tools.

Comment: Thanks. The issue was basically an endless looped $.post request somewhere else in the Application. Google Chrome didn't block any further requests but Chrome and Firefox did.